# change wpf cursor according to its type

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm looking for a way to change the cursor according to its type, for example the cursor arrow would be cur1

I'm using as follows

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="cur.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:cur"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" Loaded="TCur">


    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <FrameworkElement x:Key="cur1" Cursor="cur/cur1.cur"/>
            <FrameworkElement x:Key="cur2" Cursor="cur/cur2.cur"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
     ....
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

C#:

```
private void TCur(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (Cursor.Equals(Cursors.Arrow))
       Mouse.OverrideCursor = ((FrameworkElement)this.Resources["cur1"]).Cursor;
    else if (Cursor.Equals(Cursors.Hand))
       Mouse.OverrideCursor = ((FrameworkElement)this.Resources["cur2"]).Cursor;
}
```

i want to show a different cursor for each type of cursor, is there any way to do this?

Comment: If you just add forcecursor true there on each frameworkelement, does that give you the result you want?

Comment: I tried and it doesn't work it keeps showing only the first type of cursor `cur2` is never displayed